# Promise with setTimeout doesn't return json

Tags: javascript, json, promise, settimeout

Due to movie database API limit (40 requests every 10 seconds)I am requesting data of an api that has 4 sec of cooldown. So, I need wait 4 sec until resolve next promise.

I do understand that I have to wrap setTimeout in a Promise but how to convert response url to json?

My unsuccessful approach:

```
const pages_Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let getSearchResultsForOnePage = url => {
  //fetch
  return fetch(url);
};

let pause = time => {
  // handy pause function to await
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
};

let getAllSearchResultProfiles = async searchURL => {
  let URLs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < pages_Array.length; i++) {
    URLs.push(searchURL + pages_Array[i]);
  }
  console.log(URLs);
  let responses = [];
  for (url of URLs) {
    console.log("sending request");
    response = await getSearchResultsForOnePage(url);
    console.log("received", response);
    console.log(typeof response)
    responses.push(response);
    await pause(4000);
  }

  return responses;
};

let getAllIDs = () => {
  getAllSearchResultProfiles(mainURL).then(response => {
    data = response.json();
    console.log(data);
  });
};

getAllIDs();
```

Comment: In order to use `.json()` you need an actual `fetch()`, a fake one won't do. It also looks like `data` is an array; Arrays don't have a `.json()` method either.

Comment: @ChrisG function getSearchResultsForOnePage replaced with `return fetch(url)` the response received as Response object, but can't figure out how to convert this to json

Comment: If you have changed your code, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Be careful with variable hoisting; `url` from `getAllSearchResultProfiles` is a global variable because of `for (url of URLs)`. Use `for (let url of URLs)`. Also note that you are overwriting `response` for each URL. Pushing it into an array just pushes the same reference to the array. You may want to consider pushing the promises returned by `getSearchResultsForOnePage` into an array and using `Promise.all` instead of your current strategy.

Comment: `Promise.all` doesn't seem quite as useful here as it typically would be, because the code here is intended to be rate-limited (only one request per 4 seconds). Also despite `response` being a global-scoped variable shared across all iterations, `responses` will still correctly have each individual array - after all you are not pushing the `response` variable itself, but rather a reference *to its value*, i.e. the unique Response object corresponding to the current iteration. (This *would* be a problem if we were pushing a callback, ala `.push(() => response)`, but we are not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getAllSearchResultProfiles` resolves with the `responses` array. Later, you try to do `.json()` on this array, but this doesn't work; you have to do `.json()` on every individual item in the array. That might look something like this:

```
getAllSearchResultProfiles(mainURL).then(responses => {
  const jsonBodies = responses.map(response => response.json());
});
```

But since `.json()` itself returns a promise (i.e. the promise that resolves once the full HTTP body is received and parsed as JSON), you could instead use `.json()` from inside your `getAllSearchResultProfiles` function. (Otherwise, you'd have to use `Promise.all`.)

So, instead of doing `responses.push(response)` inside the for loop, you should do `responses.push(await response.json())`. That way the JSON response is pushed right into the `responses` array, and you'll be able to use it as-is in the `.then()`:

```
getAllSearchResultProfiles(mainURL).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Well explained and now it makes sense to me.

Comment: How do we know that `.json()` returns a promise?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 If `fetch` is spec-compilant, [.json() will return a promise](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-consume-body). But even if it does not, `await x.json()` is really the same as `await Promise.resolve(x.json())`; i.e. it will just pass the returned value directly through to `.push()`.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question though I have to say, I have read better written specs.